# How to add a search option to catalog (product page)

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I have a column available for the search bar to be placed in but i'm struggling to add a search option.

How do I go about doing this using magento version 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml
```

make sure this block is in your layout xml

```
        <reference name="header">
             <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

and call it appropriately